# Need JavaScript syntax correction

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am a newbie to JavaScript and I coded the following small JavaScript to make a postback function and its not working. I need anybody to correct it please.

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox4.Text = "nopost";
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox4.Text = "post";
        }
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function a1(){
        var hid = document.getElementById('TextBox4').Value;
        if (hid == "post") {
            alert('Posted');
        }
        else if (hid == "nopost") {
        alert('Not Posted');
        }
        }
        window.onload == function () {
            a1();
        }
    </script>
```

ASP code

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the error but use small v for value document.getElementById('TextBox4').value;

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does the Javascript get sent to the browser correctly? Do you get any errors in your browser's Javascript console?

Comment: To expand a little on jrummell's comment, "it's not working" tells us almost nothing. Always state what you expect/want to happen and what actually happens, which includes any error messages.

Comment: @jrummell, @Inerdial, @outis - Please understand one thing "JavaScript does not show errors" if syntax fails it fails to give output. Before asking `What's not working` read my question again and you can understand that I have issue with syntax as I am a niewbie.

Comment: @Madcoder.: please understand that JS *does* show errors, you just need to know where to look. Research how to open the JS console for your browser. Also, understand that "it's not working" is nowhere near enough of a problem description. My friend's computer, for example, sometimes doesn't work. Can you tell me what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property and changing `.Value` to `.value`:

```
var hid = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox4.ClientID %>').value;
```

Comment: shouldnt matter right.. he has explicitly set the id <asp:TextBox **ID="TextBox4"** runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: If TextBox4 is in a control that implements [INamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx), the ClientID would be Parent2_Parent1_TextBox4.

Comment: @Baz1nga it does matter as ASP.NET generates the ID to something like ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox4

Comment: ah ok.. I am not sure been sm time since I have dealt with those controls.. but I remember you can set the ClientId by calling sm property setter..

Answer (score 2):

You're using `==` instead of `=` for the `onload` handler assignment.

This...

```
window.onload == function () {
    a1();
}
```

should be this...

```
window.onload = function () {
    a1();
};
```

or simply this...

```
window.onload = a1;
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem might be with how you have defined the onload function change it to:

```
window.onload = a1;
```

P.S: Use the `===` operator in Javascript for type safe comparison.